# DecimalFormat - как получить результат с десятичной точкой?

Tags: java

```
String pattern = "##0.000";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

String format_balance = decimalFormat.format(balance);
```

Почему при использовании такого кода, при значении `balance = 23.158` получается `23,158`? Как добиться результата `23.158`?

Пробовал в настройках системы менять десятичный разделитель, вместо запятой точку - бесполезно.

Answer (score 6):

> Почему при использовании такого кода, при значении `balance = 23.158` получается `23,158`?

Потому что **десятичный разделитель зависит от локали.**

> Как добиться результата `23.158`?

- Если для Вашей локали по умолчанию используется запятая, то ее можно поменять на точку явным заданием десятичного разделителя:

  ```
  DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
  otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
  String pattern = "##0.000";
  DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, otherSymbols);
  ```
- Либо можно использовать локаль, в которой десятичным разделителем является точка, например:

  ```
  DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US);
  String pattern = "##0.000";
  DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, otherSymbols);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

public class TestFloat{
protected static DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
protected static DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();

protected static void setDfs(DecimalFormatSymbols dfs) {
    dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
}

protected static void setDf(DecimalFormat df) {
    df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    setDfs(dfs);
    setDf(df);

    double balance = 23.1584241515;

    System.out.println(df.format(balance));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Используй такую функцию

```
text_mgn_rashod.setText(String.format("%.2f", _fuel_millisec).replace(",", "."));
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Вроде бы достаточно простое понимание. Но хорошо

Comment: стоит ориентироваться на примеры ответов, получивших большое количество «плюсов»: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aa