# Как вывести ограниченное значение переменной в Toast

Tags: java, android

Как  сделать чтобы значение переменной  Toast_otv в которой (37.895497574646)
       выводилось как 37.89

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , " % " + Toast_otv, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Тут, к примеру, много кода по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/577733/decimalformat-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести только два знака после запятой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/389327/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this , String.format("%.2f", Toast_otv)+ "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```